# what is the best technique for delete entities (many to many) breeze

Tags: breeze

`customers` is `data.results` from query (`ids` is guid)

`selectedIds` is an array from guid.

```
function selectedMap(selectedIds) {
    var items = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < selectedIds.length; i++) {
        var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(customers, function (item) { //-
        return selectedIds[i] === item.id();
        // or item.entityAspect.setDeteted(); if true
    });
    items.push(match);
 }
 return items;
```

Is there something better?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What isn't working?  What needs to improve?

Answer (score 0):

breeze 1.5.1

```
    var countries = ['Austria', 'Italy', 'Norway']
          var query = EntityQuery.from("Customers")
                                 .where("country", 'in', countries);
```